# Changing name and ID of table inputs on submit handler for jQuery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a table that dynamically generates rows that has multiple inputs that need unique IDs and names.  I've written a submitHandler function in the jQuery validator to handle this, but I'm running into two problems:

1. My table has a header row that JQuery is including in iteration
2. All of my input types are being assigned in each loop instead of the input types for each row.

Here's my code:

```
var accessorylist = document.getElementById("accessorybody");
            var i = 1;
            $("tr").each(function(){
                var e = this;
                $('select').attr({
                    'id': 'accessory' + i,
                    'name': 'accessory' + i
                });
                $('input[type=checkbox]').attr({
                    'id': 'accessoryrequired' + i,
                    'name': 'accessoryrequired' + i
                });
                $('input[type=text]').attr({
                    'id':'accessoryqty' + i,
                    'name': 'accessoryqty' + i
                });
                alert(e);
                i++;
                alert(i);
            });
            alert(accessorylist);
            return false;
```

The alerts and return false are just debug lines for me.  I'm pretty sure for answer number two I need to specify my inputs focus on just the row (e), but I've tried a couple of different things that didn't work and I'm a bit stumped.  As for the header row, it's wrapped in a thead tag; 'accessorybody' is a tbody tag that just contains my data rows, so I don't know how or why it's being included in my loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip iterating over your row of headers by checking the contents of the `tr`, eg:

```
if (!$(this).has('th').length) {
  // run code
}
```

or you could change the loop so that it will only loop over the rows which do not contain `<th>`s

```
$('tr:not(:has(th))').each(function() { 
  // run code
});
```

In response to your second problem, you just need to give your selectors a context:

```
$('select', this);
```

That way, only the elements in the current row will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

1) use [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) jQuery selectors to skip the first row

```
$("tr:not(:first)").each(function(){ ... });
```

2) use `this` as a jQuery object to find your input elements using the row (`$this`) as context

```
var $this = $(this);
...
$this.find('select').attr({ ... })
$this.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr({ ... })
$this.find('input[type=text]').attr({ ... })
...
```

Comment: billyonecan beat you to the punch by a few minutes, but I checked this and it works too.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use th tag, or give the header row an id so you can skip it, or just skip the first row...
2. Use the [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) Function, not the global selectors.

Ex: this.children('select').attr( ...